Laravel Livewire not rendering any components
I have a simple cms I've created, using livewire on Laravel 10 using php 8.3.  It started getting these two different errors.  It had been working and no changes where made.
@extends('layouts.cms.default') @section('title', $page->name) @section('content') {!! $page->content !!} @endsection

This is output directly as text.
Undefined variable $component

For this one, the Laravel error page highlights whatever the first references component is, like  for example.
Some pages started getting these, while others still worked.  Eventually all pages with livewire on them started getting this.  I had this problem previously and it eventually started working, without any changes.  I think I may have restarted the server and that resolved it, but eventually it came back.  I have the same code base on another identical ubuntu server working fine, although even there it had the issue for a time as well, but it has not returned there.  Even if I make a basic livewire component with just Hello World in it, it doesn't render.  Non livewire pages load fine.
I've tried creating an empty livewire component, clearing caches, updating composer packages.

Did you install Livewire?

yes, I installed livewire...  It would not be working on the other server I installed it on if I had not.

Have you declared variable inside component?

Every livewire component gets one error or the other.  Any that include any blade component like  gets the undefined variable $component error, if I make a new livewire component with nothing in it, or just hello world, it gets the other issue, where it just outputs blade syntax as text.

I had exactly the same error. The issue was that I updated PHP from 8.3.4 to 8.3.12 and forgot to update /usr/bin/php symlink, so it still started 8.3.4 but loaded dependecies for 8.3.12.
